# How do I generate a virtual column of type timestamp in mysql from a json extracted date?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, json-extract

I have a field LOREM of type json in my mysql DB table BLAH.

LOREM has a property createdOn which is a date formatted like so: `2020-03-05T04:30:00.000+0000`
(This is the value retrieved by running the command:

`SELECT LOREM ->>'$.createdOn' FROM BLAH;`)

I'm trying to create a virtual generated column for created on so that querying becomes a little easier. I've tried putting this in the ddl when creating the table:

`CREATED_ON timestamp(3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CAST(LOREM ->> '$.createdOn' AS DATETIME)) VIRTUAL,`
but when inserting an entry I get an error:

> 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-05T04:30:00.000+0000'

I've tried changing the column timestamp precision from 3 to 6, but that didn't work. 
I've also tried

`CREATED_ON timestamp(3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMP(CAST(LOREM ->> '$.createdOn' AS DATETIME))) VIRTUAL,`, but got the same error.

Any idea why this may be happening and how I should solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> [11.2.2 The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP
>   Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)
>
> ...
>
> As of MySQL 8.0.19, you can specify a time zone offset when inserting TIMESTAMP and DATETIME values into a table. The offset is appended to the date part of a datetime literal, with no intravening spaces, and uses the same format used for setting the time_zone system variable, with the following exceptions:
>
> - For hour values less than than 10, a leading zero is required.
> - The value '-00:00' is rejected.
> - Time zone names such as 'EET' and 'Asia/Shanghai' cannot be used; 'SYSTEM' also cannot be used in this context.
>
> ...

```bsh
2020-03-05T04:30:00.000+0000 != 2020-03-05T04:30:00.000+00:00
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f32d99bf937bb28bc56a7c7c0e1535b3).